# Why my validator of maxlenght is state reversed?

Tags: html, angular, form-control

I m facing A mallessious issue with a simple form on my angular application.

I have the following

```
<mat-error *ngIf="errorControlsName.hasError('minLength') || !errorControlsName.hasError('maxLength')

                || errorControlsName.hasError('pattern')">{{ 'wsForm.errors.invalidFormat' | translate }}

            </mat-error>
```

[image: My form controll]

[image: the test result]

What Is blowing my ming why the error is triggered using the negation `!errorControlsName.hasError('maxLength')` For me it should be `errorControlsName.hasError('maxLength')`

m I miss understanding something ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lowercase

```
.hasError('maxlength')
```

`'minLength'` probably only seems to work because your regex in `'pattern'` already disallows it.